# USB wifi recognized by system but not as wireless interface

Tags: wifi, usb

I'm running CentOS 7.9 kernel 3.10.0-1160.25.1

I have a usb wifi dongle that recognizes under `dmesg`

```
[13220.304692] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[13220.428193] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8179, bcdDevice= 0.00
[13220.428197] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[13220.428198] usb 1-8: Product: 802.11n NIC
[13220.428200] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: Realtek
[13220.428201] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: 00E04C0001
[13220.430336] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[13220.452114] EEPROM ID = 0x8129
[13220.822828] MAC Address = d0:37:45:18:c9:59
[13220.824650] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp0s20f0u8: link is not ready
[13221.938737] R8188EU: INFO indicate disassoc
```

I installed the elrepo driver for it:

```
# yum list installed | grep 8188
kmod-8188eu.x86_64                      5.2.2.4-2.20190907git.el7_8.elrepo
```

And after I did, it shows up as an interface with `ip`

```
# ip a | grep w
391: wlp0s20f0u8: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

There's no mention of it (or anything else) in `rfkill list all`

It's not recognized by `iw`

```
# iw wlp0s20f0u8 info
command failed: No such device (-19)
```

`nmcli dev show` and `nmcli con show` doesn't list the device.

I've tried bypassing all that with `ifconfig`, `ifup`, `wpa_supplicant`, and creating a `ifcfg-` file for it, but the device doesn't seem to ever get recognized as a wireless device.

I also tried building the driver from source on github and it worked out the same as the elrepo driver.

All the help topics I can find either assume the USB isn't recognized at all or only the final step of connecting to a carrier is all that's needed, but I can't find help in this middle step.

Any advice?

Comment: If you run `sudo ifconfig wlp0s20f0u8 up`, does `ip a | grep w` show the device with `state UP`?

Comment: "8188E" IIRC that one has constant trouble with the drivers. Try a different driver. Search for Q&A about this, maybe someone mentioned which driver worked under which circiumstances...